# Java Jena: Display Model in Text Area

Tags: java, swing, jena

I need to display the model into textarea. Can you guys give me solution about this case?
Thank you.

```
private void btnViewXML(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                            
    boolean readFile = checkFileExtension(file);
    String xmlText;
    if(readFile==false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File is not valid!");
        System.out.print(extension);
    }else if(readFile==true){
        try {
            File owl_file = new File(file);
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(owl_file);
            OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
            xmlText = model.read(reader,null);
            model.write(OutputArea.append(S),"RDF/XML-ABBREV");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Genii. Can you please add more detail about what you have tried and the error you are seeing?

Comment: `textArea.setText( xmlText )`